# Is "Since + clause" a noun clause or adverbial clause in this phrase?

Tags: syntax, prepositions, clauses, conjunctions

I wanted to know if "since + clause" was an adverbial clause or noun clause in the phrase or after the phrase "it's been a while since I've seen you.".

I was thinking “it's been … since” might be like an adposition or a preposition or a circumposition

And maybe the phrase “it's been … since” might be like or mean “ago” or “before”.

Is “it's been … since” a phrase?

What might you think ?

Comment: It's neither. "Since" is a preposition, so "since I've seen you" is a preposition phrase. It functions as modifier in clause structure.

Comment: Why do you think 'since' is a preposition? And if you think 'since' is a preposition Do you think 'a while' is an adverbial noun or subject complement? Or what might you think 'a while' is?

Comment: Trad grammar classifies this "since" as a conjunction. But "since" can also uncontroversially occur as a preposition when it has an NP as complement, and there's no basis for assigning it to different categories according as it takes an NP or a clause -- or no complement at all. Compare "since the meeting" (NP comp) / "since we arrived" (subordinating conjunction + sub clause) / "I haven't seen her since (adverb, no complement). This is just a matter of varying complementation, which is commonplace. I take "a while" to be an NP functioning as predicative subject complement of "be".

Comment: I think you are showing that trad grammar shows that this "since" after noun and before a clause or this "since" between 'time' and a clause is a conjunction but I think you showed that this "since" is a preposition so I'm thinking what might "since" be or what do you think "since" might be. What might "it" be?

Comment: I consider "since" a prep. I've posted an answer. Also, see here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/since)

Comment: I thank you for showing that or for replying. And I was thinking why do you think "since" is a preposition and what might "it" be in that sentence "it's been a while since I've seen you.".

Comment: I've answered your first question in the first para of my answer below. "It" is a dummy pronoun functioning as subject of the sentence

Comment: I think I am not seeing that you showed or answered why you think "since" is a preposition. I'm sorry if I'm asking too many questions but what is "it" showing or meaning?

Comment: Why haven't you respond to that?

Comment: May you respond to that?

Comment: I answered that in the first paragraph of my answer, where I said it can occur as a preposition when it has an NP complement ("I haven't seen him **since the meeting**").

Comment: I think you showed that you think "since" before a clause is preposition but now I think you showed that you think "since" before noun phrase is a preposition too so I'm thinking what "since" before a clause might be or I'm thinking if "since" before a clause is a preposition or a conjunction.

Comment: It's **always** a preposition. Please don't keep asking the same question.

Comment: May I ask more questions?

Comment: What is "it" referring to? Or what does "it" mean?

Comment: And if "since I've seen you" is a prepositional phrase, Is  "since I've seen you" an adjectival prepostional phrase or an adverbial prepositional phrase?

Answer (score 1):

> *It's been a while since I've seen you.*

Traditional grammar classifies this "since" as a conjunction. But "since" can also uncontroversially occur as a preposition when it has an NP as complement, and there's no basis for assigning it to different categories according as it takes an NP or a clause -- or no complement at all.

Compare:

*since the meeting* (NP comp)

*since we arrived* (subordinating conjunction + sub clause

*I haven't seen her since* (adverb, no complement).

This is just a matter of varying complementation, which is commonplace.

The addition of the word "since" to the class of preposition is controversial, but in my opinion justified.

I take "a while" to be an NP functioning as subjective predicative complement of "be".